# Did India shoot down any Pakistani F-16 on 27th February 2019?

Tags: united-states, india, pakistan

According to DG ISPR of the Military of Pakistan, Gen. Asif Gafoor, on 27th February 2019, Pakistan Air Force's jets engaged IAF's jets and ["shot down two IAF jets"](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/defence/india-shot-down-pak-air-force-f-16-fighter-jet-one-iaf-pilot-missing-in-action-confirms-govt/articleshow/68183776.cms).

On the same day, India claimed that [they shot down](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/defence/india-shot-down-pak-air-force-f-16-fighter-jet-one-iaf-pilot-missing-in-action-confirms-govt/articleshow/68183776.cms) a Pakistani F-16. [In the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEGlCyJx_es) it could be seen that, during the press briefing, before reading out the statement, the spokes person of Indian Ministry of External Affairs, said

> "Namashkar! Good afternoon! I welcome you all to this media briefing. I am joined by Air Vice Marshal R G K Kapoor. I will read out a prepared statement on recent developments on India-Pakistan front. We will not take any questions after my statement. ..."

while the [assistant chief of Air Staff](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/articleshow/68205197.cms?utm_source=contentofinterest&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=cppst) of the IAF Air Vive Marshal RGK Kapoor was sitting completely silent. Also, reading a prepared statement, and not taking questions afterwards seemed to be fishy.

During the [press conference on 27 February 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tW8yp0qCko&t=308s),  [Gen Gafoor said](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/mar/03/pakistan-denies-indian-claims-it-used-us-f-16-jets-to-down-warplane):

> "... apart from that, I was watching Indian media said that they too shot down one of the F-16s of Pakistan. First thing to say is, Pakistan has not used any F-16 particularly in this entire action, or there is no such news that any of the Pakistan's jets were down. Now let us talk about...".

[After more than 32 hours](https://mumbaimirror.indiatimes.com/mumbai/cover-story/maun-ki-baat/articleshow/68193077.cms) of the original incident, at the evening of the next day, 28th February 2019,  [India showed a wreckage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7bw2kHkOXc) of, **allegedly**, an AIM-120C5 AMRAAM missile. [RGK Kapoor was seen reading out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75MngfjhXOs) from a pre-prepared written statement. Also, [personnel from one of the Indian ministries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3OqLotTbcw) was seen to be administering the event.

Pakistan's Foreign office dubbed Indian claim as "[completely baseless](http://www.newindianexpress.com/world/2019/mar/10/indias-claim-of-shooting-down-paf-f-16-fighter-jet-completely-baseless-pakistan-foreign-office-1949270.html)".

Secondly, there was [not much row seen from the US-side](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/03/09/india/india-pakistan-jet-intl/index.html) regarding the use of F-16s by Pakistan.

Was any Pakistani F-16 really shot down by Indian Air Force on that day?

.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over a year later, we can say this claim is **very unlikely to be true**. [In April 2019](https://foreignpolicy.com/2019/04/04/did-india-shoot-down-a-pakistani-jet-u-s-count-says-no/), *Foreign Policy* magazine reported that according to two anonymous US officials, Pakistan is not missing any F-16s. The US has not made any further statements on the matter as far as I can tell. One might argue that the US has some interest in covering this up, but it's not clear to me that they do. More significantly, I don't see any independent verification of the evidence or documentation  India claims to have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answers are always informative to read. I came across [this news article](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/did-india-shoot-down-an-f-16-of-the-pakistan-air-force/article26830937.ece) : *Last week, Foreign Policy quoted an unnamed U.S. defence official as saying that the U.S. had physically counted PAF F-16 planes and “all aircraft were present and accounted for.” **Responding to questions on the issue later, a U.S. Defence Department spokesperson said they “weren’t aware” of any such investigation.***

Comment: India lying to fuel nationalist fervor. What a shocker.