# Did Pakistan shoot down an Indian Su-30 in 2019?

Tags: war, india, pakistan

As of 2021 Radio Pakistan still [claimed](https://www.radio.gov.pk/27-02-2021/paf-celebrating-surprise-day-today-on-second-anniversary-of-operation-swift-retort) that in the 2019 shootout with India they shot down two IAF aircraft, a MiG-21 and a SU-30

> PAF had shot down **two** Indian fighter jets namely MiG-21 **and Su-30** where the former pilot Wing Commander Abhinandan Varthaman was caught by Pakistan Army after his safe ejection and falling into the Pakistani side of the line of control.

That the MiG-21 was shot down and its pilot captured by Pakistan (and eventually returned to India) was covered by [plenty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhinandan_Varthaman) of sources/evidence.

**What evidence is there for the Pakistani claim they also shot down a Su-30?**

(Related, but not the same Q, on a claim by India during the same events [Did India shoot down any Pakistani F-16 on 27th February 2019?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43618/did-india-shoot-down-any-pakistani-f-16-on-27th-february-2019))

Comment: Looks like India admitted a loss in Aug 2019 claimed to a crash https://youtu.be/3-Y8lsA_d4w?t=32 but this was months after the Feb combat.

Comment: Looks like there were fairly large crowds at the site of the (latter) incident, so rather unlikely this could have been misdated (i.e. used as cover-up) https://youtu.be/BJhrJDtswVo?t=65

Comment: FWTW they seem to lose ~one Su-30/year to various mishaps https://www.bharat-rakshak.com/IAF/Database/Accidents/listing.php?qacid=74&qt=TY

Answer (score 2):

No one can verify this except the Indian ministry of defence. Because, as far as I recall, on February 27, 2019, the Indian government banned all journalists (both print and TV) from reporting from that area where that specific dogfight took place. So, no one has any evidence.

Also, this is very sensitive information, both for the morale of IAF personnel and the diplomatic image of India.

The common logic given in favor of India's loss of one Su-30MKI on February 27th, 2019 is as follows -

1. India lost a total of 11 units of Su-30MKIs due to crashes.

[image]

2. India lost an additional unit of Su-30MKI on February 27th, 2019.

The total gap in the number of their Su-30MKIs was 12 units.

Therefore, they placed a supplementary order in **June, 2020** for 12 Su-30MKIs to replenish their squadrons.

[image]

.

> **References**

1. [IAF, IA and IN Aircraft Losses Database](https://www.bharat-rakshak.com/IAF/Database/Accidents/listing.php?qacid=74&qt=TY)
2. [India to Make Emergency Purchases of 12 Su-30MKI](https://militarywatchmagazine.com/article/india-to-make-emergency-purchases-of-12-su-30mki-and-21-mig-29-fighters-to-counter-china)

Comment: When did they place the order? Because they lost one to a crash in August for sure, although that loss seems unlikely related to Pakistani action.

Comment: @Fizz, They placed the order on June 18th, 2020.

Comment: Why does it require the Indian government to confirm? Why not, for example, an independent journalist with video of the attack or photos of the wreckage?